# How to solve second order differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

There are questions on the site regarding second order differential equations, but none of the rules seem to apply to this question.

So $y''= e^{-2t}+10e^{4t}$, and some conditions are $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$.

How do I find y? I understand how to do first order differential equations.

Comment: use the way to solve first order diff. equation for finding $y'$ first, and then try to find $y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

$$y'' = 0$$

gives $y_c = c_1t + c_2$. Guessing the particular solution as $Ae^{-2t} + B e^{4t}$ we have

$$4Ae^{-2t} + 16Be^{-4t}= e^{-2t} + 10e^{4t} \implies A=\frac{1}{4} \quad \quad B = \frac{5}{8}$$

So we have

$$y(t) = c_1 t + c_2 + \frac{1}{4}e^{-2t} + \frac{5}{8}e^{4t}$$

subject to $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 0$. Imposing these conditions we see

$$1 = c_2 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{5}{8} \implies c_2 = \frac{1}{8}$$

$$0 = c_1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{2} \implies c_1 = -2$$

$$y(t) =  \frac{1}{8} - 2t + \frac{1}{4}e^{-2t} + \frac{5}{8}e^{4t}$$

**Approach 2:**

Let $v(t) = y'(t)$. We then have

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = e^{-2t} + 10e^{4t}$$

$$v(t) = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t} + \frac{10}{4} e^{4t} + c_1$$

Using $v(0) = 0$ we see

$$0 = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{10}{4} + c_1 \implies c_1 = -2$$

Now plugging back in $y'(t)$ we have

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t} + \frac{10}{4} e^{4t} - 2$$

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{4}e^{-2t} + \frac{5}{8} e^{4t} - 2t + c_2$$

Using $y(0) = 1$ we see

$$1= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{5}{8} - 2 + c_2 \implies c_2 = \frac{1}{8}$$

We again get

$$y(t) =  \frac{1}{8} - 2t + \frac{1}{4}e^{-2t} + \frac{5}{8}e^{4t}$$